# How does one get an Enum's members into the global namespace?

Tags: python, enums

Python now has an Enum type (new in 3.4 [with PEP 435](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-342/), and alse [backported](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34)), and while namespaces are a good thing, sometimes Enums are used more like constants, and the enum members should live in the global (er, module) namespace.

So instead of:

```
Constant(Enum):
    PI = 3.14

...

area = Constant.PI * r * r
```

I can just say:

```
area = PI * r * r
```

Is there an easy way to get from `Constant.PI` to just `PI`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The officially supported method is something like this:

```
globals().update(Constant.__members__)
```

This works because `__members__` is the `dict`-like object that holds the names and members of the Enum class.

I personally find that ugly enough that I usually add the following method to my Enum classes:

```
@classmethod
def export_to(cls, namespace):
    namespace.update(cls.__members__)
```

and then in my top level code I can say:

```
Constant.export_to(globals())
```

Note:  exporting an Enum to the global namespace only works well when the module only has one such exported Enum.  If you have several it is better to have a shorter alias for the Enum itself, and use that instead of polluting the global namespace:

```
class Constant(Enum):
    PI = ....
C = Constant

area = C.PI * r * r
```

Comment: So it does work well as long as you don't have duplicate names in those exported enums?

Comment: @JürgenA.Erhard: Yes.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW — this is more of a comment rather than an answer — below is the beginning of a function from some old code I wrote which implements it's own named `int`-like enumerated-value objects which were added to the global namespace by default (there's no named container `Enum class` involved). However it's doing something similar what's shown in your own answer, so I think it a good overall approach because it's worked well for me.

```
def Enum(names, values=None, namespace=None):
    """Function to assign values to names given and add them to a
    namespace. Default values are a sequence of integers starting at
    zero. Default namespace is the caller's globals."""
    if namespace is None:
        namespace = sys._getframe(1).f_globals  # caller's globals

    pairs = _paired(names, values)
    namespace.update(pairs)  # bind names to cooresponding named numbers
        . . .
```

The point being, as far as implementing something for the current `Enum` class module goes, I'd suggest adding something like it or the `def export_to()` method shown in your own answer to the `Enum` *base* class in the next Python release so it's available automatically.